# Numpy load in Jupyter notebook "IOPub data rate exceeded."

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, pickle

I have stored a big dictionary file in numpy pickle format. I can open it in older jupyter notebook app. But, in newer version when I run this line, I see IOPub error.

```
big_dict = np.load('a_large_dictionary.npy').all()
```

The error:

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.
```

It seems something is going on in the background that I don't have control on. It is strange because I am not trying to load/view the content of this file in NotebookApp!

Any idea? How can one load a big file without editing the Notebookapp config? (again, I don't want to show the content I just read from file into the variable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in case of error, `numpy.load` will print the content. First, try to load the pickle file in terminal or any other python environment other than Notebook to find the error. 
In this case, loading an older version of pickled numpy needs encoding argument.  This code fixed the problem:

```
big_dict = np.load('a_large_dictionary.npy', encoding='latin1').all()
```

Answer (score 4):

using

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=2147483647
```

when launching notebook fixed my problem. Source: https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/issues/528